# Median without VBA on string fields

Tags: string, ms-access, median

I have the SQL below:

```
SELECT
(
(SELECT MAX(Score) FROM
    (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Score FROM Posts ORDER BY Score) AS BottomHalf)
 +
(SELECT MIN(Score) FROM
  (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT Score FROM Posts ORDER BY Score DESC) AS TopHalf)
) / 2 AS Median
```

'Score' needs to be converted into a value (from string) first. I've tried encasing all the 'score's with val() but this returns an error on MS Access (J-sql).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you try any other conversion functions? Or is `Val()` the only thing you tried?

Comment: Val() is only one. I'm new to sql!

Comment: You could try `SUM(CDbl(Score))` or `SUM(CLng(Score))`. `CDbl` and `CLng` are type conversion functions in Access. They will convert to decimal and long integer, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for tip OverMind. I managed to get you suggestion to work for: SELECT MAX(CLng(nz(systolicBloodPressure,0)))

Comment: However it does not work for the statement above. Returns error saying that I tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression " as part of an aggregate function.